# How is a Model supposed to signal change? via events? via mediator/eventaggregator? via INPC?

Tags: mvvm, dependency-injection, inotifypropertychanged, mediator, eventaggregator

Suppose upon a button click in the View, the ViewModel calls an asynchronous, long and tough calculation on the Model (with Model being business logic and data, as per Wikipedia). During this calculation the Model is spitting out one calculation result after the other (which are of a different kind, it's not like an ObservableCollection is useful here) and the View is supposed to display them the moment these part-results are ready.

*How can it do that?*

1. Via an **EventAggregator**? Caliburn Micro has one but that would mean I had to reference Caliburn Micro in my business logic - this can't be right, can it?
2. Via **INPC**? I have the impression that wherever I implement INPC, that class is going to be exposed to be bound to. I obviously wouldn't want a class with business logic exposed to the View just so I can bind to some of it's properties. So I'd need an indirection with a separate class (implementing INPC) whose properties I set from the business logic that the View can bind to. Now what I have done feels like creating a ViewModel that the model is tied to. - this can't be right either! (Not exposing it, but wrapping it with a ViewModel subscribing to PropertyChanged feels like a pretty severe violation of DRY)
3. So I guess I need to use plain old **events**? Having read Mark Seemans book and blog on DI I have the impression this is wrong too. Since subscribing to an event in the constructor is [wrong](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2013/09/06/di-and-events-constructor-subscription/). [His suggestion](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2013/09/11/di-and-events-composition/) is to reverse the logic and let the DI container inject an `IObserver<>` into the business model class, which will call `Next()` on it. That would mean the ViewModel will implement potentially quite a few `IObserver<>` interfaces? Is that it?

I need a bit of guidance here, thanks!